# How to replace featured image upload option with the post media image option

Tags: post-thumbnails, media-library

I am looking for a way to insert custom URL links in featured Image as well. Currently Featured image tab is only having these basic settings -

[image: featured]

But I want  to add custom URL links to my featured image as well, I checked the add media button is having this feature as shown in the screenshot -

[image: media]

Let me know how could I add this in my featured Image tab as well.

I checked this http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/    & http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-custom-meta-boxes-in-wordpress-posts-and-post-types/  but unable to sort, let me know how could i manage it.

I am not very sure whether I can replace the whole featured image upload option with the media with the post media image options as it provides these extra facilities OR I can add an extra custom field option for my Linked URL setting,let me know the easiest option to manage it.